# Resharper Transient cache always hitting the disk causing Visual Studio 2017 slowdown

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

Whenever I hit save within Visual Studio 2017 devenv.exe maxes out a core for 5-10 seconds and I see lots of activity to hundreds of files in this folder.

```
%APPDATA%\Loacl\JetBrains\Transient\ReSharperPlatformVs15\v12_5794bede\SolutionCaches\projectname----\Db.000332.sst
```

I have my resharper cache set to c:\JetBrains\ however it seems to use both this directory and APPDATA.

What is resharper/VS doing and why is it slowing my PC down massively? I have a 12 core threadripper and a 3gb/s PCIE nvme SSD. Pressing ctrl+s lags out my keyboard from typing for several seconds.

This does not always happen. How can I solve the CPU/Disk activity when saving ?

I have disabled full solution analysis and followed the resharper performance guide. I have disabled intellitrace, code lense and everything else I can find, yet it still runs terribly.

[image]

Comment: Maybe contact ReSharper support?

Comment: They are too slow and always ask for performance snapshots, except their performance snapshot and bug reporter tool always crash so I can't take one. Thought I'd try my luck here first.